# What kind of preposition should be used before the telephone number?

Tags: prepositions

A single-choice exercise:

> Please call Gina *_*_ 834-8911.
>
> - A.in
> - B.of
> - C.at
> - D.for

Why use the preposition "at", can I replace "at" by "on" ?

Answer (score 2):

I think *on* refers to the medium.

> call me **on** my cellphone and not **on** my landline.

On the other hand, **at** refers to that particular thing.

> call me **at** my work OR call me **at** 3437.33.443

*A little more information. But this is my opinion*

I think we also use *call me **on*** if we have more than one number. This case is true especially the opposite person knows both of your numbers.

> "Vicky, bbye. We'll talk later." 
>   "Okay, I'll call you this evening" 
>   "Yeah, but call me **on** my new number 923.2393.23, the old number I don't use anymore."

Comment: I would say that "at" refers to the destination. A phone number is a destination.

Comment: @D_Bester Oh yes. I used *that particular thing* as I thought *numbers* as a *destination* may sound odd!